# Why doesn't my class function using str_replace work the same as inline php code using str_replace?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, str-replace

Why doesn't my class function using str_replace work the same as inline php code using str_replace? I think it's something to do with encoding but I have used utf-8 everywhere and I can't figure this out.
The function is supposed to change Polish characters in a string into %.

My class function:

```
public function searchTitle($title) {
    $polskie_literki = array("ą","ę","ł","ó","ś","ć","ź","ż","ń","Ą","Ę","Ł","Ó","Ś","Ć","Ź","Ż","Ń");
    $titleReplaced = str_replace($polskie_literki,"%",$title);
    return $titleReplaced ;
}
```

And if I call the class function and inline code like this:

```
    $searchText = "człowiek";
    $polskie_literki = array("ą","ę","ł","ó","ś","ć","ź","ż","ń","Ą","Ę","Ł","Ó","Ś","Ć","Ź","Ż","Ń");
    $titleReplaced = str_replace($polskie_literki,"%",$searchText);
    echo "inline result :" . $titleReplaced . "<br>";

    $szukaj = new Search();
    echo "class function result: " . $szukaj->searchTitle($searchText ) . "<br>";
```

I get different results:

```
inline result: cz%owiek
class function result: człowiek
```

Any ideas? I dont want to have to use this inline code if I dont have to.

Comment: show how you call the class function please

Comment: $szukaj = new Search();
    echo "class function result: " . $szukaj->searchTitle($searchText ) . "<br>";

Comment: [Can't Reproduce](https://eval.in/private/540fe5359ca87d) Please post your entire class.

Comment: The only thing that really makes sense here is that you have your source files saved with different encodings

Comment: Sam you are right. Stupid mistake Ive been troubling myself with for the past 2 hours. Thank you, can I give you points/rep somehow?

Comment: IMO the fact you say thanks is 1000x better than most people on here ;)